# Using split pop and join all at once can it work?

Tags: javascript

I really  love Javascript and I wrote my code like this. I feel like it should work. Am I doing it in the wrong order? If it won't work like this why not?

```
var mydate = new Date();
alert( mydate.toLocaleTimeString().split(":").pop().join(':'));
```

`split()` makes it an array, `pop()` takes off the end of the array, `join()` makes it a string again right?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use [`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) with a negative end/second argument.

[`Array#pop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) returns the last element, but not the array itself. `slice` returns a copy of the array with all emements from start without the last element.

```js
var mydate = new Date();
console.log(mydate.toLocaleTimeString().split(":").slice(0, -1).join(':'));
```

Comment: So why does pop() not work like that? Generally I have noticed in JS when you return a new variable you can further manipulate it with more extension functions.

Comment: "So why does pop() not work like that?" Because that is what the specification calls for. And you can use the chain method with pop when you expect the last item to be what you want.

Comment: imagine you were required to write a pop function. In your function, you just want to return a single element, not the array. But when you write a split function, you will want to return an array. So it really depends on the purpose of the function.

Comment: OK I get it if you pop() an array it will make the array shorter but if you reference it as an extended method it returns the thing you cut off. Thanks everyone!

Comment: yea, and for your question. You first split the time string with ':' into an array. Then you pop the array so it return the last element in the array, which is a string. Now you want to join the string with ':'. You will get an error because join does not work with a string but an array.

Answer (score 3):

No, [`pop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) will remove the last element from the array and **return it**.

To achieve what you're trying, you'll need to first assign the result of `split()` to a variable you can then reference:

```js
var mydate = new Date(),
    myarr  = mydate.toLocaleTimeString().split(':');
    myarr.pop();

console.log(myarr.join(':'));
```

Comment: too fast.. haha.. was still finding reference for pop

Answer (score 2):

if all you want to achieve is hours:minutes, you can just simply do this

```js
var mydate = new Date();
console.log(mydate.getHours() + ':' + mydate.getMinutes());
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use method chaining where next method in the chain uses the output of the previously executed method. Reason it's not working is because "join()" method is a prototype of an array but "pop()" returns an array element which doesn't aforementioned method that's why the error.
refactor your code as below:

```
  var myDate = new Date(),
      myDateArr = myDate.toLocaleTimeString().split(':');
  myDateArr.pop(); // Remove the seconds
  myDate = myDateArr.join(':'); // Returns string
  console.log(myDate);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
var mydate = new Date();
alert( mydate.toLocaleTimeString().split(":").slice(0, 2).join(":"));
```